# Does is matter whether you write a matrix using vector columns or rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given say a set of vectors in R^3. (1,1,2) , (-1,-1,3) , (6,2,2) Does is make any difference if the vectors are written as rows to form a matrix or columns? I just ask because one lecturer will write them as columns and the other one as rows and just wanted to make sure it doesn't matter which way I use

Comment: It matters depending on what you want to do with that matrix. For example, if you are given several vectors and you want to determine an easy basis for the space generated by these vectors, you can put those vectors in rows, then row reduce the matrix, the rows in the row reduced form form a basis for this space, the columns however do not (in general). 
You could also put the vectors in columns and column reduce the matrix, the columns in the reduced form will form the same basis as before, but the rows might not.

Comment: Generally, it matters indeed ! unless you limit the discussion to such properties, like determinant, which are the same whether the matrix is or not transposed

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802115/why-are-these-vectors-expressed-as-row-vectors-and-not-column-vectors-when-to-w?rq=1 This may help you gain some insight? 

But I think sometimes it's just to maximise the space on the paper